# Strange Response When Restarting Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, webserver, tomcat7, restart

When i tried to restart tomcat, i got these:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

However, tomcat is running fine. but i have no idea what are these about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break them down one-by-one

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7 --> Your tomcat base dir
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7 --> Your tomcat home dir
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp --> tomcat's temp dir path
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr  --> Path to your JRE
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar  
        ^--> The jars that are on the class-path when this vm was launched
```

The reason why you are displayed these logs 2 times is due to the `restart` command. The first logs are issued when `shutdown` was called, and immediately afterwards `startup` was called, thus the second layer of logs.

It is a perfectly normal behaviour of Tomcat

Answer (score 2):

When you restart Tomcat two VMs are executed. The first one connects to Tomcats shutdown port, sending the shutdown String you defined in server.xml, and stops the server. The second one starts the server and is closed afterwards.

The BASE directory is where Tomcat is looking for its libraries and default directories. The HOME directory is where the current Tomcat instance is working with. I.e. if you have several Tomcats they can all use the same base directory. The TMP directory is where it (guess what) stores temporary files.